# Integer command line arguments all showing up as 2

Tags: c++, int, command-line-arguments

So i am writing a program that takes in an int, and returns something to do with the bits that represent the int. However, when I put an int in the command line and immediately print it out it, it prints 2.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

~  ./a.out 8

I can only take in one parameter for main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void foo (int ii, int x){
   static int p;
   k= x<<ii;
   .
   .

}

int main(int x) {
    cout << x << endl;
.
.
.
return 0
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have a hunch what's happening here, but I need to see your code to confirm it.

Comment: C or C++? Writing a multi-language source file is hard work!

Comment: Congratulations, you've written a program that outputs `2`. Now explain to us why this was undesirable.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("%d\n", argc); return 0; }`

Comment: This is pretty serious. The only way to fix it is by learning some C/C++. Try consulting a textbook, or one of the many, many online introductions which you should have consulted before coming here.

Comment: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) - For a comprehensive breakdown of why `int main(int x)` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter passing does not work the way you appear to believe it does.

There are precisely two signatures for `main` that are guaranteed to work:

```
int main()
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The latter is the one you use when you want to parse command line arguments. Here `argc` is the argument count, i.e. the number of passed arguments (including the name of the command itself) and the length of `argv`. `argv` is an array of C-style strings that holds the arguments.

So, when you call

```
./a.out 8
```

then `argc` is 2, `argv[0]` is `"./a.out"`, `argv[1]` is `"8"`, and `argv[2]` is a null pointer. If you want to use the first command line argument as a number, you have to parse `argv[1]` with `std::istringstream` or `atoi` or similar, as in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if(argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "No argument was given.\n";
    return -1;
  }

  std::istringstream parser(argv[1]);
  int x;

  if(parser >> x) {
    std::cout << x << " * 2 = " << x * 2 << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cerr << "The argument was not a number.\n";
    return -2;
  }
}
```

As a side note, **because this is not something you can depend upon,** this also explains why you get the output `2`. When you write

```
int main(int x) {
```

`x` takes the value of `argc`, and what would have been `argv` is ignored, for low-level reasons that have to do with the way the arguments are laid out in memory before the jump to `main`. When you call the program with `./a.out 8`, that value is 2, and so `x` is 2 in your code. This is not guaranteed to work by the C++ standard, but it is likely to happen on all platforms as it did on yours.